# Five months ago, I {decided/have decided} to learn how to play the piano

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-simple

> Five months ago, I {decided/have decided} to learn how to play the
> piano.

Is **"Five months ago"** a definite time?

I have read that when there is a **definite time,** I should use the **simple past tense.** For example:

> I **ate** my dinner **two hours ago.**

When there is **no definite time,** I should use the **present perfect tense.** For example:

> I **haven't** **seen** my best friend for a **long time.**

Comment: The sequence ***Five months ago, I have [done something]*** is invalid, because that initial adverbial clause implies ***a completed action in the past***, which clashes with the implied "relevance to time of utterance" of the Present Perfect verb form.

Comment: ***...but*** many native speakers might be happy enough with ***I've had lunch two hours ago***, even though strictly speaking that should be Simple Past ***I had lunch...*** (its fine by me). Curiously, I find that construction completely unacceptable if the adverbial element is "fronted", and the contraction "expanded", to give ***Two hours ago I have had lunch***.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you accept the definition the dictionaries give of ***AGO***, like for example [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ago):

> earlier than the present time (that is, earlier than NOW, the time of speech),

then your expression of time ***five months ago*** is very definite.

So your sentence should be:

> Five months ago (which is *in August 2020*), I ***decided*** to learn (how) to play the piano. ([Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=learn+to+play+piano%2Clearn+how+to+play+piano%2Clearn+to+play+the+piano&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clearn%20to%20play%20piano%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clearn%20how%20to%20play%20piano%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clearn%20to%20play%20the%20piano%3B%2Cc0) prefers ***learn to play the piano*** rather than ***learn how to play the piano***.)